# OnGUI in VR not showing

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I have included the following line to show a simple `timer` in the top left corner of a scene, which works of course, but when I tick the `Virtual Reality Supported` check-box and put on an Oculus Rift, it disappears.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), Time.time.ToString());
}
```

What am I missing? What should I do additionally to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OnGUI() does not work in VR**. Instead use world space canvas UI.

I did the following for the Gear-VR.

Add a canvas (or other UI elements containing "Canvas" component) to your scene. Set render mode to **World Space**. This can be found on the render mode drop down list for the UI Canvas object:

[image]

I ended up going for an 800 x 600 canvas.

For the timer itself I used `Time.deltaTime`.

Here is my whole `PlayerController` script:

```
void Start ()
{
 timeLeft = 5;
 rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
 count = 0;
 winText.text = "";
 SetCountText ();
}

void Update() {
 if (gameOver) {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
} else {
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = timeLeft.ToString("0.00");
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
        winner = false;
        GameOver(winner);
    }
 }
}
void GameOver(bool winner) {
 gameOver = true;
 timerText.text = "-- --";
 string tryAgainString = "Tap the touch pad to try again.";
 if (!winner) { // case A
    winText.text = "Time's up.\n" + tryAgainString;
 }
 if (winner) { // case B
    winText.text = "Well played!\n" + tryAgainString;
 }
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
 float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
 float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y"); 
 Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);    
 rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
 if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up")){
    other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    count = count + 1;
    SetCountText ();
    if (!gameOver) {
        timeLeft += 3;
    }
 }
}   
void SetCountText ()
{
 if (!gameOver) {
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
 }
 if (count >= 12) {
    winner = true;
    GameOver(winner);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. `winText` and `countText` and `timerText` are UI `text` game objects. Right?

Comment: Yes (and if you declare eg: `public Text winText;` you can set it from within Unity).

Comment: Thank you. One question: How do I eliminate the fast-pace fraction part that shows milliseconds, so that only a second-counter shows?

Comment: This line keeps mine to two decimal places `timerText.text = timeLeft.ToString("0.00");`

Comment: I have not included that line and only have `Time.time.ToString();` but I think the two decimal places are due to `Time.time`

Comment: No, they're due to `("0.00")`. If you only want to see seconds, use `("0")`. See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry!  My bad . .  You are right.  I did `Time.time.ToString("0");` and it works as I want it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`OnGUI` does not work in VR. You have to use [world space canvas UI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).